# Salesforce Knowledge to create Knowledge Articles through Permission Set

Tags: knowledge

User has Read permission on Article Type .
Through Permission set , I have given user Manage Articles permission (To create/Edit )

Still user cannot create knowledge article . What else needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be possible if in User Record, `Knowledge User` checkbox is not selected.

**Update based on comments**

> Question: Manage Article checkbox is enough to provide write access to create any article . Will the user be able to create only those articles of the types for which he has access from profile or articles under any article type? Also , is there any way to give write permission through Role?

Let me share you what is the relation between Manage Article permission and Article specific permissions.

Selecting a Manage Article permission does not mean he can able to create or edit any article types. You need to explicitly give permission to respective article types.

You cannot able to give write permission through Role. Salesforce doesn't provide that feature.

For example,

**KCS Reader**

This user will view the article.

[image: KCS Reader]

**KCS Candidate**

This user will create and edit the article.

[image: KCS Candidate]

**KCS Contributor**

This user can delete the article as well as other functionalities.

[image: KCS Contributor]

Comment: A few other questions - Manage Article checkbox is enough to provide write access to create any article . Will the user be able to create only those articles of the types for which he has access from profile or articles under any article type?  Also , is there any way to give write permission through Role?